# How to get the shared librarys in order to make omxplayer work?

Tags: fedora, libraries

So basically I am trying to make omxplayer work on my raspberry PI 2 model B running on fedora arm 23,
I downloaded the last .deb package for omx player and unpacked it and am actually trying to get the shared libraries necessary to run it.

Here are some outputs explaining further what s going on :

```
#ldd omxplayer.bin | grep "not found"
    libavutil.so.55 => not found
    libavcodec.so.57 => not found
    libavformat.so.57 => not found
    libswresample.so.2 => not found
    libpcre.so.3 => not found
```

I tried `#dnf provides "*/libavutil.so.55"` in order to know what package to download but I didn't get any. `Error: No Matches found`
Any ideas on how to get these shared librarys otherwise?

Here is more information on what I am trying to do [link](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/54031/how-to-display-hq-videos-on-rpi-2-model-b-running-fedora-arm)

So after doing export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib64:/usr/lib/omxplay‌​er
I got some of those librarys and the output of `#ldd omxplayer.bin | grep "not found"` became

```
    libpcre.so.3 => not found
    libssl.so.1.0.0 => not found
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => not found
```

Someone suggested I do `#dnf install openssl-devel` but I already had it

```
`Package openssl-devel-1:1.0.2h-3.fc23.armv7hl is already installed,skipping.Dependencies resolved. Nothing to do. Complete!`
```

`#ls /lib |grep libssl` gives the following

```
libssl3.so
libssl.so
libssl.so.10
libssl.so.1.0.2h
```

Answer (score 1):

`libavutil.so.55` is provided by the `ffmpeg-libs` from `rpmfusion`:

```
$ dnf provides "*/libavutil.so*"
ffmpeg-libs-3.0.2-4.fc24.x86_64 : Libraries for ffmpeg
Repo        : rpmfusion-free-updates
$ rpm -ql ffmpeg-libs | grep libavutil
/usr/lib64/libavutil.so.55
```

You probably don't have this repository installed:

http://rpmfusion.org/Configuration

Comment: Correct answer but @Ezwig Don't use those because the Fedora repo ones won't exploit the pi hardware (and may not work at all); [in this case](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/54041/5538) that's a library that's part of the bunch included with `omxplayer`.  Copy the `usr/lib/omxplayer` player directory into `/usr/lib` and **run `ldconfig`.**

Comment: ou. I read you are using F24 (where I searched for these files). So the problem will probably be that you installed Debian package into Fedora.

Comment: Ah -- there was a critical step missing from that answer WRT to adding the directories to the linker cache for `ldconfig`.  I will edit that in...

Comment: @goldilocks in this context, it makes sense. Though it is not the most standard way of doing things on OS level :)

Comment: It is `openssl-devel` and `pcre-devel`, but I am afraid it might be different version in Fedora.

Comment: You should not overwrite the path, but append to it: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib64:/usr/lib/omxplayer` or so. But the versions might differ, since you install binary for different distribution.

Comment: @Jakuje i only overwrote it beacause i knew it was empty :) , thanks for teh advice though

Comment: @goldilocks since those are some librarys i have recent versions of should i make symbolic links having the required name on the ones i already have?will that work?

Comment: **NO NO NO NO DO NOT ADD TO LD_LIBRARY_PATH!!!**  This is not what it is for and doing this except for a temporary test will come back to haunt you, I promise. You need to add the path to the linker cache via a file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` (see that long answer).